# Print Shop Product Creation, I Need Help Setting Products Up Right

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options, product-prices

I have made this thread in the hopes that someone having had my difficulty can shed light on my issue or even just some brilliant mind find a solution that I have not seen yet.  Thanks in advance!

My name is Forrest and I own a digital and screenpriting shop in Ontario.  I purchased a print shop theme a few weeks back with multiple plugins including ajax cart and file upload etc.. and everything went very well until I started creating my products. In digital printing (business cards, post cards etc..) There are many simple changeable variables (shipping option, finish option etc) that must change according to the complex variables (size, quantity etc) and inside the complex variables such as size, I must have very specific sizes as I have small printers and very large printers so from 100,250,500,750 to 1000 I will use my small printer and after that I jump to 2,500,5000,7500,10000 for my large printer as it becomes very inexpensive at that point.

With Magento I am unable to set those specific quantities and I can not simply print 1,250 it must be either 1000 or 2,500 as I know if I could print other quantities I could just set the quantity increase to 250 and leave it at that.

All this being said, my initial thought was to make quantity a custom option.. Until I realized I would not be able to change the other variables according to the price of the quantity (size, finish, shipping etc)  which is a big problem.

I looked everywhere for a solution and found a few that looked viable but turned out not to be.  I found a extension that allowed me to set custom quantity breaks however it did not format well with my theme and looked awful.. Next up I found Absolute price which allows me to set a custom option to be absolute price which will change the base price on the product which would work amazing if it worked in coalition with percentage markup on custom options.. I found that when I would set quantity as a custom option to absolute price and then make the shipping a % markup of the price, it would not change according to the new absolute price.

Any thoughts on the matter and ideas on how I can set this up to work properly?

Thanks,